# getting blank email using python

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x

i am trying to email using python, but getting blank  email this is using css files and js files

```
import smtplib
import urllib2
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import sys

server = "localhost"
sender = "send email id"
receivers = ["receiver email id"]
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

SUBJECT = "devsmoke run"
msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = receivers
html = """ 
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/slate/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-X9JiR5BtXUXiV6R3XuMyVGefFyy+18PHpBwaMfteb/vd2RrK6Gt4KPenkQyWLxCC" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!-- Local resources -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=".html/report.css">
        <script src=".html/report.js"></script>

        <!-- Reporting data -->
        <script src="report.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
"""
part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")
msg.attach(part2)
try:
    s = smtplib.SMTP(server)
    s.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
    print("Successfully sent email")
except Exception, err:
    print(err)
    print("Error: unable to send email")
```

i am getting email but without any content. files report.js and .html directory are in the same directory as of this python code

Comment: You can not use JavaScript or remote CSS in emails.

Comment: You can't refer to local resources from an email. You need to give a full web path to those resources, or embed them.

Comment: how to embed them

Comment: i have tried using the web path then also facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

Add the mail content to MIMEMultipart object.

```
msg.attach(MIMEText(html, "html")) # You can have html or text in content
```